# VMWare Workstation: Auto backup/clone?

Tags: virtual-machine, backup, vmware-workstation

Is it possible, and how, to have VMWare Workstation automatically (scheduled or scripted) to clone the currently running image so that it can be used for backup purposes?

Answer (score 3):

See this article : ["Backing up VMware Workstation VMs "](http://daveclarkesblog.blogspot.com/2008/07/backing-up-vmware-workstation-vms.html).
The article describes a very simple backup script, which you can schedule to backup your VMs.